# I need Method that takes a vector and a circle and looks if they intersect

Tags: c#, math, mathematical-optimization

I have a vector in 2d space that starts at A and ends at B.
I also have a circle in 2d space with the Position C and has a radius of r

I need to know if the vector AB does intersect with the circle(center:C,radius:r)

what would be the most efficient way to do this calculation?

Comment: is this a vector and circle located in 2d space? 3d space? If 3d, is the normal of the circle an input? What have you already tried? Please share your research.

Comment: Well, judging how a 2d-only answer was accepted, it seems a 3d-compatible answer isn't necessary so I edited the question to reflect that. This question would be improved if it showed any research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given **A** and **B** are endpoints of a line. It can be represented as a vector with direction from **A** to **B** with a magnitude as the distance of **AB**.

The line **AB** doesn't intersect with the circle when the distance between the center of the circle **C** and the line **AB** perpendicular to the direction of the line is greater than the radius **r** of the circle.
Refer to the image below for visualization.

[image]

### Calculating the distance between the line and the center of the circle:

**Step 1:** Get the line equation of **AB** from the formula below.
Here **x1** = **A.x**, **x2** = **B.x**, **y1** = **A.y**, **y2** = **B.y**.

[image]
Solving, a line equation of the form **ax + by + c = 0** is obtained.

**Step 2:** Calculate the distance **d** from the formula below.
Here **x0** = **C.x** and **y0** = **C.y**.

[image]

Finally, check whether the distance between the line and the center of the circle **d** is greater than the radius of the circle **r** or not. If yes, then the line lies outside the circle.

Comment: i dont fully understand the last formula. what is a b or c? are these the coordinates of the points or the length of the vectors?

Comment: ax + by + c = 0 is the line equation of AB. Apologies for the inconvenience, I've updated the answer